# Install Live Search for Magento - package not found

Tags: composer

I've installed Magento with sample data on a virtual machine. Now I'm trying to install Live Search for it. I used the instructions from this [link](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-merchant-services/live-search/onboard/install.html?lang=en). As the instruction says, I run the command below:

```
composer require magento/live-search
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Problem 1
    - magento/live-search 2.0.0 requires magento/module-live-search-metrics 2.0.0 -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
    - magento/live-search 2.0.1 requires magento/module-live-search-metrics 2.0.1 -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
    - magento/live-search 2.0.2 requires magento/module-live-search-metrics 2.0.2 -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
    - magento/live-search 2.0.3 requires magento/module-live-search-metrics 2.0.3 -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
    - Root composer.json requires magento/live-search ^2.0 -> satisfiable by magento/live-search[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require magento/live-search:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require magento/live-search:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

As I can see, it says `magento/module-live-search-metrics` does not exist, but I couldn't find anyone else who has the same problem as mine, which means this is only my problem.

Comment: I believe this feature is only available for Adobe Commerce version (old Magento Enterprise)

Comment: Thank you for that. I will try to install Adobe Commerce then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you are installing the Magento Enterprise Old.